# Chatroom App with Node.js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, socket.io, chat

I want to write a chat-room application(web client as well as Android app). This chat-room app will have multiple chat rooms and user can join/leave any of them at any time. Messages that user send will be broadcasted to everyone in that chatroom.

I have recently started learning node.js and I would like to build backend for this app in it. I did some research and found tutorials on how to do that. Almost all the tutorials I saw were using socket.io. Is that the best of way of doing an app like this?

Maybe I did not completely understand how socket.io works but the issue I have is that, implementation says you have to add socket.io.js client side library in order to communicate with server. Does that mean only the web client can communicate what about android application?

Do I have to write my web server and service in the same package with socket.io or can I create an independent service?

Comment: socket.io, as far as I know, works perfectly with android aswell: http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/ .